# Moving a 10g database to 11g with rman backup

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

Following Doc ID 369644.1, I'm trying to restore a 10g database into a 11g database ( version 11.2.0.1.0), which is in other server.

What I did on 11g server:
- Generate full rman backup of 10g database
- Copy pfile, control file and full rman backup from 10g to 11g

```
C:\> oradim -new -sid BDSPROD -intpwd bdsprod
C:\> SET ORACLE_SID=BDSPROD
C:\> rman
RMAN> connect target sys
RMAN> SET DBID=367107039
RMAN> STARTUP force nomount PFILE=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\PFILE_bdsprod.ora
RMAN> restore controlfile from 'C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\CTRLFILE_BDSPROD.CTL';
RMAN> alter database mount;
RMAN> crosscheck backupset;
RMAN> delete expired backupset;
RMAN> catalog start with 'D:\RMAN_bdsprod\';
RMAN> restore database;
RMAN> recover database;
```

After this step, I followed Doc ID 558408.1

```
SQL> connect sys/bdsprod as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter database open resetlogs upgrade;
```

Now, how can I startup database? It seems that only way is doing:

```
SQL> STARTUP upgrade PFILE=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\databas\PFILE_bdsprod.ora;
```

In that way, only sysdba can connect to database.
Other ways like just "startup" or "startup pfile=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\PFILE_bdsprod.ora;" it gets errors.
Is there any way to start 11g database?

```
SQL> startup PFILE=C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\PFILE_bdsprod.ora;
ORA-32006: BACKGROUND_DUMP_DEST initialization parameter has been deprecated
ORA-32006: USER_DUMP_DEST initialization parameter has been deprecated
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 709836800 bytes
Fixed Size 2179136 bytes
Variable Size 201330624 bytes
Database Buffers 499122176 bytes
Redo Buffers 7204864 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
Process ID: 12712
Session ID: 5 Serial number: 3

SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file 'C:\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\INITBDSPROD.ORA'
```

Comment: You're not moving with an rman backup, you're essentially upgrading. You'll have to now follow a upgrade procedure.

Comment: Like Phil says, the database have to be upgraded after restore.Have a look at http://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/how-to-restore-10g-rman-backup-to-11g/

Answer (score 1):

After `alter database open resetlogs upgrade` the database should be open.This statement replaces the `startup upgrade` command.  If this kind of upgrade is possible than you are after the [startup upgrade](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/upgrade.htm#i1012182) step in the upgrade procedure and you should continue after this step. But you should have prepared the database in the way as described in the steps before [startup upgrade](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/upgrade.htm#i1012182).

I never tried this way to upgrade. You should do this kind upgrade only if you are very experienced with Oracle know exactly what you are doing. Otherwise you should choose an upgrade path that is recommended by oracle like *Database Upgrade Assistant* or a method like import/export. Check the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/upgrade.htm)