# How to restore 11gR2 fullbackup to 12c database in rman

Tags: oracle, rman

I need to transfer my database from Oracle 11gR2 to 12c database. It will be in same computer. I took full backup of Oracle 11gR2 database. Then I remove Oracle 11gR2. I installed Oracle 12c and I tried to restore my backup. I could restored spfile, controlfile, datafiles.. But I couldn't do

```
RMAN> ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00704: bootstap process failure
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-00904: "I". "UNUSABLEBEGINNING# ": invalid identifier
Process ID: 3377
Session ID: 125 Serial number: 5
```

What should I do to open database? Should I do Pre-Upgrade script ? I couldn't understand to do pre-upgrade script step..

Comment: upgrade using backups is possible, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24718/moving-a-10g-database-to-11g-with-rman-backup and the note Doc ID 369644.1 mentioned by @Macco. But it is rather complex and the way you do it is nonsense,, because you already have a 11g database to upgrade. A step in the upgrade using backus i to restore the 11g  database from the backup

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. Oracle binaries of a certain version correlate to the Oracle Database dictionary of the same version.

RMAN is a backup and recovery tool. It is NOT an upgrade tool.

You need to restore and recover you database on 11g binaries. From there you can upgrade your database to 12c.

You can have many versions of Oracle Database installed on the same host. The different binaries go into different ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: When you restore a database with a newer oracle home you have to open the database with `alter database open resetlogs upgrade;`